access daily pending txs historical data
I am an academic researcher in finance, currently working on Txs Fees on Ethereum. I am looking for a database where I can find the daily number of pending transactions on Ethereum over a large amount of time (ideally since 2015). If you guys know any data service provider or individual that could help me find this data it would definitely make my day.
I obviously found this (https://etherscan.io/chart/pendingtx) and this (https://etherscan.io/dashboards/daily-pending-tx) but it doesn't allow to download nor to check the data earlier than 1month.
